# Not able to install npm module material-design-icons

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, freeze

### I have

- System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Node: v14.17.6
- NPM: 6.14.15

#### Internet speed by https://www.speedtest.net/

[image]

I tried to install `npm i material-design-icons`

But, it's not being installed. After few minutes the terminal looks like

[image]

### System resourses while installing

[image]

Comment: Does it eventually error out? Do you have enough storage on you computer?

Comment: `Do you have enough storage on you computer?` Yes, i have enough space on my computer. SSD free storage (100GB) and amount of free RAM is about 2GB

Comment: Aren't your PC behind a proxy, that does not let the npm requests through?

Comment: No, there is no proxy

Comment: Does it error out if you wait long enough?

Comment: yeah, i have re installed the system again.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I am behind proxy node v 16.13.0 and NPM v 8.1.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: It hangs after the status ```   reify:node-gyp-build: timing reify:audit Completed in 5124ms```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after approx 11 mins it finished installing. I had 75Mbs download speed. According to answers [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/518) you can or should use should install **material-design-icons-iconfont** instead.

```
npm i material-design-icons

added 1 package, removed 1 package, and audited 916 packages in 11m

124 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on `reify:node-gyp-build: sill tarball no local data for material-design-icons@https://re`

you have to wait 20 minutes and it will finish. The library is just too large. After that I added

```
  imports: [
    ...
    MatIconModule,
    ...]
```

and

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
```

to app.module.ts